# Double outer Join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table A that looks like this

```
ID     AValue
----------------------
3      Tom
5      John
9      Mike
```

and table B that looks like this

```
ID     BValue
----------------------
2      Nancy
3      Maria
9      Clara
10     Sophia
```

I am trying to join both tables  to get this result

```
ID      AValue         BValue
------------------------------
2       <NULL>         Nancy
3       Tom            Maria
5       John           <NULL>
9       Mike           Clara   
10      <NULL>         Sophia
```

If i try to left outer join I would miss the records that do not have match in A
and If I try the right outer join i would miss the records that do not have match in B

any other way I can use?

Comment: it is call `FULL OUTER JOIN`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you need is `FULL OUTER JOIN`

```
SELECT ID = coalesce(a.ID, b.ID), AValue, BVlaue
FROM   TalbleA a FULL OUTER JOIN TableB b
       ON a.ID = b.ID
```